# Fatal Throwable Error in HasRelationships, Class not found (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model

In the posting function of my app, posts exist in a three-stage hierarchy comprising Genre, Category, and Post. Genres have many categories, categories have many posts. When I try to access my posts/create view, I get an error message saying that Class 'Genre' cannot be found. Here are the relevant models:

Genre:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Category;

class Genre extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function category() {
      return $this->hasMany('Category');
    }
}
```

Category:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Genre;
use App\Post;

class Category extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = array('name', 'genre_id');

  public function post() {
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
  }

  public function genre() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Genre', 'genre_id');
  }
}
```

Post:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Category;

class Post extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = array('title', 'slug', 'category_id', 'body');

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
  }
}
```

Here's the use section and create function in PostController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use App\Genre;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
      $categories = Category::with('genre')->get();
      return view('posts/create')->withCategories($categories);
    }
}
```

And the create view itself:

```
@extends('layouts/main')
@section('stylesheet')
  <link href="/css/postcreate.css" rel=stylesheet>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="content">
<h4 class="font-display postcreate_title">CREATE POST</h4>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" class="postcreate_form">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="postcreate_form-group">
    <label for="title" class="postcreate_form-label">Title:</label>
    <input id="title" name="title" class="postcreate_form-input" required maxlength="255">
  </div>
  <div class="postcreate_form-group">
    <label for="category_id" class="postcreate_form-label">Category:</label>
    <select id="category_id" name="category_id" class="font-body postcreate_form-category" required>
        <optgroup label="Fiction">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            @if($category->genre()->name == 'Fiction')
              <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endif
          @endforeach
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Poetry">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            @if($category->genre()->name == 'Poetry')
              <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endif
          @endforeach
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Essay">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            @if($category->genre()->name == 'Essay')
              <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endif
          @endforeach
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Journal">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            @if($category->genre()->name == 'Journal')
              <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endif
          @endforeach
        </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="slug" class="postcreate_form-label">Slug:</label>
    <input id="slug" name="slug" class="font-body postcreate_form-input" required minlength="5" maxlength="255">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="body" class="postcreate_form-label">Body:</label>
    <textarea rows="30" id="body" name="body" class="font-body postcreate_form-input">Enter text here.</textarea>
  </div>
  <input class="xlight" type="submit" value="Publish">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

It was suggested over on the Laracast boards that I remove the parentheses from the calls to 'genre' in the if statements, but this has no effect. Similarly, `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan config:cache` were suggested and had no effect.

Comment: Can you use `php artisan tinker` and create a Post, Category, and Genre and access them? That'd be where I'd start troubleshooting. I do agree with laracasts people on removing the `()` for the genre calls and checking to see if the error is the same.

Comment: Try passing `App\Models\Genre::class` instead of a string `Genre`. to the relationship methods.

Comment: Even though the () removal didn't do anything by itself, when I combined Ohgodwhy's suggestion with that, it appears to have solved the problem! Thanks.